# 3D matrix, multiplication on last dimensions

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D-matrix `A`, with size lets say `3x12x100`. The first two dimensions define `3×12 matrices`, the latter one is simply the linear index. I want a very simple operation on these 100 matrices. For all these matrices, i want them multiplied with its conjugate transpose. With a very simple for loop, i can create this:

```
data = data;
A = zeros(100, 12, 12);
for i=1:100
    A(i, :, :) = data(:, :, i)'*data(:, :, i);
end
```

But i like clean code, so i dont really prefer this for-loop. I have done some searching and sometimes find something like `mtimesx` (which is a custom made MATLAB function from 2010). I think i am missing something very obvious (as usual), because this seems a fairly easy operation (its just an "element-wise" matrix multiplication).

Comment: I think your code looks clear and simple and that any other thing that hides the loop will just make it less ovbious

Comment: Okay, thank you :) Was just wondering, it is such a simple operation (apart from the conjugate transpose).

Comment: I think you can do this without the loop by appropriately `permute`ing the matrices and adding singleton dimensions, then applying the `dot` operator along the right dimension. I don’t think it is worth while to figure out how exactly to write this. The loop code you have will be clearer, and likely faster.

Comment: My code is however terribly slow. The total number of entries can easily be `800000` (so the result is that many `24x24` matrices), which can easily take around 10 minutes. I have a lot more (simple multiply/add) operations preceding this calculation and these take less than a second. Got any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Cris was right, you can find an example from this MatlabCentral post

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10161-3d-matrix-multiplication#answer_413531

Answer (score 2):

The size of my actual matrix is `3x12x862400`. My original script takes about 10 minutes or longer, a variant on what @FangQ posts fixes it in a matter of seconds. My new code is as following, note that it still is under construction and i still need to validate it:

```
data = rand(3, 12, 862400) + i*rand(3, 12, 862400)
data2 = conj(permute(data, [2 1 3])); % conjugate transpose each matrix
% my data matrix contains 862400 3x12 matrices with complex numbers

Ap = permute(data2, [2 1 4 3]);
Bp = permute(data, [1 4 2 3]);
M = Ap.*Bp;
M = sum(M, 1);
M = permute(M, [2 3 4 1]);
```